# why does `this` refer to the global object in closure

Tags: javascript, this

```
var num = 1;

var obj = {

    num: 2,

    getNum: function() {
        return (function() {
            return this.num;
        })();
    }

}

console.log(obj.getNum()); // 1
```

the JavaScript code's result is 1. So `this` refers to global object rather than obj.

Comment: I get `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/3k3Lbawn/

Comment: No, `this.num` refers to function: `return (function() { ...}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @sp00m That's because in your jsFiddle the code is wrapped in a `window.onload` handler and `var num` is a _local_ variable.

Comment: @Vohuman You're right, nice catch: http://jsfiddle.net/2bd9qasy/

Answer (score 2):

All else being equal, `this` refers, when used *directly* within a function, to **the object of which the function is a method** (member), when that function is called in the typical way of `obj.method()`. Directly means directly; use within a function nested within the method, whether anonymous or immediately-invoked or otherwise, does **not** qualify.

In your case

```
return (function() {
    return this.num;
})();
```

the function is not a member of any object, hence there's no `this`, hence `this` is the global object (or null in strict mode).

Just because the function where you are using `this` is nested within a function which is a method is **not** enough. The function where you are using `this` must be the method itself.

To get the behavior you want, you have several alternatives:

```
getNum: function() {
  return (() => this.num)();
}
```

This works because fat arrow functions use lexical `this`.

Another idea, already shown in another answer:

```
getNum: function() {
  var self = this;
  return function() {
    return self.num;
  }();
}
```

In this context, by the way, there is no need to enclose the function in parentheses to force it to be a function expression that you can call immediately. Merely by virtue of being on the right side of the `:`, it's already an expression.

Yet a third approach:

```
getNum: function() {
  return function() {
    return this.num;
  }.call(this);
}
```

Here we are forcing the `this` of the anonymous function to be the `this` of `getNum`, by explicitly using `call`.

For the definitive answer, see [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

#### Note on the term "closure"

In your question, you appear to be using the term "closure" to mean "nested function". Although your nested, anonymous, immediately-invoked function may be a closure in some extremely narrow technical sense, using the term this way is likely to confuse both yourself and others. Your function does not satisfy either of the two following generally-accepted criteria for being a closure:

1. It does not "close over" (use) any variables from the surrounding scope.
2. It is not returned to the outside world as a function value carrying along with it references to such variables from the surrounding lexical scope.

Hence, it would be much clearer to simply refer to this function as a "nested function".

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function `this` depends on the execution context, so it's important how the function is called.

If the calling context does not set `this`, it's different in strict and non-strict mode.

In non-strict mode, it refers to the global object.
In strict mode, its `undefined`. Note that `undefined` can be actually set to something else.

To set the said context, you need to invoke function as a property of an object, as in obj.getNum() invocation. In would give an object scope to the function, but it does not have anything to do with another function call in which you are trying actually access `this`.

Following code illustrates it:

```
var num = 1;
var obj = {
  num: 2,
  getNum: function() {
    var outerThis = this;
    return (function() {
      return {
        innerThis: this,
        outerThis: outerThis,
        innerNum: this.num,
        outerNum: outerThis.num
      };
    })();
  },
  getNumStrict:function() {
    "use strict"
    var outerThis = this;
    return (function() {
      return {
        innerThis: this,
        outerThis: outerThis,
        outerNum: outerThis.num
      };
    })(outerThis.num);
  }
}
console.log(obj.getNum());
// Object {innerThis: Window, outerThis: Object, innerNum: 1, outerNum: 2}

console.log(obj.getNumStrict());
// Object {innerThis: undefined, outerThis: Object, outerNum: 2}
```

As you can see, `this` is a controversal concept in JavaScript, and you can easily get by without it.

To make private properties private you can create them in a function scope and return a function returning a copy of an interface instead of an object reference:

```
var num = 1;
var createHaveNum = function(initial) {
  var num = initial;
  var getInterface;
  var setNum = function(x) {
    num = x;
    console.log("setting num");
  };
  var getNum = function() {
    console.log("getting num");
    return num;
  };
  getInterface = function() {
    return {
      getNum: getNum,
      setNum: setNum
    };
  };
  console.log("Instance is initialized.");
  return getInterface;
};

var obj = createHaveNum(2); // create an object, obtain a reference in form of a function

var i = obj(); // obtain an interface
var j = obj(); // do it again, interface to same object
j.setNum = undefined; // does not break internal state, object is intact
console.log(i.getNum());
i.setNum(3);
var getNum = i.getNum; // reference function
console.log(getNum()); // invoke without a scope, no problem
var other = {getNum: i.getNum}; // put in another object
console.log(other.getNum()); // call with another context, no problem - same scope as before.
/*
Instance is initialized.
getting num
2
setting num
getting num
3
getting num
3
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `obj` does not exist when the object literal is defined, so it can't be closed over. On top of that, closure operates on the scope, and you don't have a scope outside the function.

At the moment the literal is being evaluated, there is no `obj`. When evaluating that statement, the object literal is evaluated first (the right-hand operand to the `=` operator *must* be evaluated first), then assigned to the newly-declared variable `obj`.

To make matters worse, closure in ES is on the scope and ES5 (and below) only have function-scope. You don't have an outer scope to close over, besides the global scope.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: If you log `this.num` _outside_ the IIFE (but inside of `getNum`), it logs the correct value (`2`). Can you explain why the reference changes _inside_ the IIFE?

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I was somewhat confused what you were referring to in the original version of your answer.

Answer (score -1):

To get the "desired" result, you'd have to redefine `getName` as below:

```
getNum: function() {

    var that = this; //the enclosing object
    return (function() {

        return that['num'];

    })();

}
```

Comment: You solution is correct but your explanation is wrong.

Comment: @Mathletics, could you please point out the parts of my explanation that is wrong?

Comment: The third paragraph is all wrong. Functions are indeed objects, but `this` inside the IIFE points to `window`, not to the function `getName`. (Thus your explanation for `undefined` is also wrong; that was correctly addressed in the comments above.)

Comment: @Mathletics, yes, seen the issue. You are right, thanks for pointing that out.